# @folder and +folder

Tags: matlab

What is the meaning of the following folder names in MATLAB?

- `@folder`
- `+folder`

I've created a class `Tata.m` which uses the `classdef` syntax.
Should I put it in an `@folder` or a `+folder`?

I've looked at the documentation but it is not really clear
in which cases the `@folder` should be used and in which cases the `+folder` should be used.

Answer (score 41):

The `+folder` piece is a MATLAB package folder. If you place `Tata.m` in a location like `+folder/Tata.m`, it will be known to MATLAB as the class `folder.Tata`. If you place it in a folder like `someOtherFolder/Tata.m`, or `someOtherFolder/@Tata/Tata.m`, it will be known to MATLAB as `Tata`.

It can be useful to place a `classdef` file in a class directory like `@Tata` to allow you to put the definition of some (or all) methods in separate files.

The [doc](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brfynt_-1.html) has more details.

EDIT: To attempt to clarify the `@` directories: historically, a class `Tata` with methods `methodOne` and `methodTwo` would require the following files:

```
somePlaceOnThePath/@Tata/Tata.m
somePlaceOnThePath/@Tata/methodOne.m
somePlaceOnThePath/@Tata/methodTwo.m
```

In the "new" object system, you can still use the layout above without modification. At the other extreme, you can place the entire implementation of `Tata` in a single `classdef` block in:

```
somePlaceOnThePath/Tata.m
```

If you have some large methods, or want to split up the implementation of the class `Tata` into several files to make parallel development simpler, you can take use a classdef like this:

```
%# somePlaceOnThePath/@Tata/Tata.m:
classdef Tata
    methods
         result = methodTwo(obj, arg)

         function methodOne(obj)
             disp('hello from methodOne');
         end
    end
end
```

And also

```
%# somePlaceOnThePath/@Tata/methodTwo.m:
function result = methodTwo(obj, arg)
% do stuff with obj and arg
end
```

Strictly speaking, the advance declaration of `methodTwo` in the `classdef` is optional because it's using the default access specifiers. If you wanted to have `methodTwo` be a private method, you could place it in a `methods (Access = private)` block.

Comment: ok, thanks Edric, now, I understand the +folder but not the @folder

Comment: Documentation link is broken and I can't quite figure out what it was supposed to be. I'm also still struggling to understand the meaning and significance of a "MATLAB package folder".

Comment: Hm, I'm not 100% sure now either, perhaps it was meant to be http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html or http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/organizing-classes-in-folders.html