# MATLAB superclass can not be found on the MATLAB's search path

Tags: matlab, class, oop

I have 2 paths :

- `C:\controller\functions\verifyModel.m`
- `C:\OGVD\prod\KMLP\controller\controllerStatus.m`

#### verifyModel.m

```
classdef verifyModel 
    methods(access=public)
        function...
    end
end
```

#### controllerStatus.m

```
classdef controllerStatus < verifyModel     
   .....
end
```

but when I run `controllerStatus.m`, I got an error as the class I used isn't in the path 
how could I add `verifyModel` to the path ?

Answer (score 0):

Before usage of controllerStatus use:

```
addpath('C:\controller\functions\')
```

Also, you might want to put in in a [`@ folder`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_oop/organizing-classes-in-folders.html). These folders are added to the path whenever they are visible, so as they are a subfolder of your current path(`pwd`).

Or add 'C:\controller\functions\' to your static matlab path, what I do not recommend.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781866/folder-and-folder).

Comment: I don't want to add it with addpath within the class , is there a way so that the file is added automaticaly ?

Comment: Humm! I interested for @folder , I didn't used before : so I can put the class in : C:\controller\functions\@function\verifyModel.m Then no need to call addpath ?

Comment: C:\controller\functions\@verifyModel\verifyModel.m The @folder should have the same name as its classdef file. There's no need to call addpath as long as C:\controller\functions\ is on your path or your current folder

Comment: I have error with path : I just changed : C:\controller\functions\@verifyModel\verifyModel.m and from controllerStatus.m : classdef controllerStatus < verifyModel

Comment: Do I need something in controllerStatus  ?

Comment: If verifyModel can't be found when it's in c:\controller\functions then creating a @verifyModel folder under functions and putting verifyModel there wont work either.  The @[folder] only works when the folders parent is on the Matlab path.  As far as I can tell, @[folder] only make sense for classes that have methods in multiple files.