# Access data files from subfolder of current script directory

Tags: matlab

I have been working on MATLAB scripts.
Basically, I have a lot of functions and data files (collectively known as kernels):

I want to organize it a little bit. 
The idea is

1. to create a subfolder named `functions` and save all functions in it.
2. Another `kernels` and save all data kernel files in it.

Later by adding these paths at runtime, all the scripts should be able to access these functions and kernels without giving the full path to them, i.e. The script should search it in the subfodlers too.

Applying `addpath(genpath(pwd));` worked for functions but it couldn't access kernel files

e.g. What if I want to access file named `naif0010.tls` inside subfolder `kernels`.

It didn't work. Any suggestions.

Example:

```
% Add the current script directory and subfolders to search path
addpath(genpath(pwd));

% Load NASA Spice (mice) to the script here
% add MICE reference path to MATLAB
addpath('C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\extern\mice\src\mice');
addpath('C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\extern\mice\lib');

% Load leap second kernel
% If the leapsecond kernel is placed in script directory
% This file is present in pwd/kernel/naif0010.tls
cspice_furnsh('naif0010.tls');
```

Comment: Have a look to this post, maybe if can help you.

[Matlab folder class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781866/folder-and-folder)

Comment: thanks, but nope, still confused

Comment: This depends on how robust the function `cspice_furnsh` is, but you might be able to get away with a relative path like `cspice_furnsh('kernels/naif0010.tls')`, if that helps at all.

Comment: @nispio: this worked very well after adding pwd earlier.
Just updated my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things to keep in mind. First, your current working directory (`pwd`) is in the Matlab path by default, so you don't usually need to explicitly call `addpath` in order to use scripts, functions, or data files there.

Also, in many cases you can access files by providing a *relative path* rather than an absolute path.  In your case, this would look like

```
cspice_furnsh('kernels/naif0010.tls')
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with some work around which I know is not the correct answer but for now I can go ahead....

```
addpath(genpath(pwd));
% Basically just forming full path of the data file
leapSecondsFile = fullfile(pwd,'kernels','naif0010.tls');
cspice_furnsh(leapSecondsFile);
```

Still waiting for correct answer or suggestions :-)

```
Update:
```

Thanks nispio's comment above, The correct way is :

```
% Load current directory and subfolders
addpath(genpath(pwd)); % This is not necessary 
cspice_furnsh('kernels\naif0010.tls');
```

Comment: You can do away with your temporary variable if you want and just call `cspice_furnsh(fullfile(pwd,'kernels','naif0010.tls'));`

Comment: Indeed, that can be done :-)
Although I got the correct answer...updated above

Comment: You probably get away with loading the file without adding `pwd` to your path.  By default `pwd` is already in your path.

Comment: @nispio: Great, that's true, many thanks. In addition, Can you write your suggestion as an answer instead of a comment, so that I can accept it as an answer to this question. Thanks